# UICollectionView prevent multiple taps/calls to didSelectItemAt

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, segue

I am using Single Tap on Collection View Cell to call `performSegue` inside `collectionView didSelectItemAt`. Sometime specially when app is launched first, `performSegue` is delayed, not sure why and user taps again & again. In this case `performSegue` is gets called multiple times and new view controller is pushed many times(number of taps). Any particular reason for this delay? If not then I will have to implement following:

```
var alreadyTapped = false
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    alreadyTapped = false
}
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if alreadyTapped { return }
    alreadyTapped = true
    performSegue(withIdentifier: Constants.Segue.DETAIL_VC, sender: collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath))
}
```

Or if there is a better way to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

Try below code,

```
  override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            performSegue(withIdentifier: Constants.Segue.DETAIL_VC, sender: collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath))
        }
    }
```

Comment: Isn't 'didSelectItemAt' being called already on main thread? Also it didn't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can do a Bool flag... but I prefer a delay...

```
var didSelectTime = Date()

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    //MARK:- Prevent multiple calls. If elapsed time between calls is less than 1 sec, do nothing
    if Date().timeIntervalSince(self.didSelectTime) < 1.0 {
        self.didSelectTime = Date()
        return
    }
    self.didSelectTime = Date() 
    .....
}
```

Comment: Dude, thanks a lot, it's so cool solution!